# Create string from all row elements pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a csv file and I would like to create a string with all the elements of each row. Lets say that I have the following csv...

```
trump,clinton
google,microsoft,linkedin
linux,windows,osx
data science,operating systems
```

I would like to create a string like so; `trump&clinton` | `google&microsoft&linkedin` and so forth. I did import the file and create a df with pandas. The solution doesn't have to be with pandas, if can be done with `import csv` that is acceptable as well.

I need one string per row... each row will become its own string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df.apply('&'.join, axis=1)
```